# SwiftUI Text ignoring newline and tab characters

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am attempting to render a multiline text block in SwiftUI using the Text component. I'm passing it a string that contains newlines and tabs, however whenever it is rendered, all of these special characters appear to be removed from text and the content is all rendered in a straight line. Does anyone have any ideas how to convince SwiftUI to actually let this be multiple lines?

```swift
let s = "{\n\t\"hey\":\"there\"\n\n\n}"
Text(.init("`\(s)`"))
```

The above code renders as:

[image: Screenshot of the straight line]

Comment: Provided code snapshot is not compiled, needed real code to avoid guessing.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](http://swiftlydierkes.com/swiftui-multiline-text/) modify your code accordingly.

Ex.

```
Text(“In SwiftUI Multiline text is great. \n Right?”)
         .lineLimit(nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
let s = "{\n\t\"hey\":\"there\"\n\n\n}"

Text("`\(s)`")
```

or

```
 Text("\(s)")
```

or

```
Text(s)
```